# Dropdown is not working for mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, intl-tel-input

I used jquery plugin ,the dropdown worked for desktop view however dropdown is not working in the mobile browser. how could i fix this? here is the code snippet.

```
var mob_num = $('#mobile-number');
window.default_country_iso_code 
mob_num.intlTelInput({
  defaultCountry: "auto",
  geoIpLookup: function(callback) {
    $.getJSON('/geo_api/get_country_iso_code', function() {}, "jsonp").always(function(resp) {
      var countryCode = (resp && resp.country_iso_code) ? resp.country_iso_code : "";
      callback(countryCode);
      window.default_country_iso_code = resp.country_calling_code
      mob_num.val("+" + resp.country_calling_code + " ");

    });
  }
});
```

and this is the html.

```
 <div class="control-group <%= "error" if @errors.present? && @errors.messages.has_key?(:phone)  %>" >
   <label class="control-label required" for="mobile-number">Phone </label>
    <div class="controls">
      <input class="intl-tel-input" type="tel" id="mobile-number" name="client[phone]" value="<%= params['client']['phone'] if params['client'].present? %>" required>
          <% if @errors.present? %>
             <% if @errors.messages.has_key?(:phone) %>        
                 <div class="help-block"><strong><%= @errors.messages[:phone][0].to_s %></strong></div>
              <% end %>
           <% end %>
         <div class="help-block"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

css used for this.

```
#wrapper {
    width: 70%;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

.setup-wizard-logo-container {
    margin: 10px 0;
}

.box {
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .067);
    .border-radius(5px);
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #fff;
}

form {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.intl-tel-input {
    height: 28px !important;
    width: 97%;
}
```

The rest of the css is added by the library itself to it's container.

Comment: can you update you css of the relevant part

Comment: @Ramesh i updated my question.

Comment: What does `not working` mean?

Comment: when i clicked to it, dropdown is not opening .

Comment: @NeerajAmoli What about your media query? There may be several reasons can occur in css. Add your media queries

Comment: even if i removed all  the media query of this page, still issue persist.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me,i just increase the z-index of one of it's library css class.

```
.intl-tel-input select{
  z-index: 3;
}
```